# Is the Lorentz group compact (and if not, is U(1)?)

Tags: group-theory, topology

A common statement in any quantum field theory text is that only compact groups have finite-dimensional representations, and that the Lorentz group is not compact, since it is parameterised by $0\leq (v/c)<1$. Fair enough, but $U(1)$ is parametrised by $0\leq \theta <2\pi$, so why is $U(1)$ compact? Should they be described as closed instead, or am I getting lost?

Comment: Only compact groups have finite dimensional *unitary* representations, AFAIK. If you allow for non-unitary representations then you can find something finite-dimensional.

Comment: to "only compact groups have finite-dimensional representations" : No, all unitary irreducible representations of abelian groups are one dimensional no matter whether they are compact or not.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, the unit operator on a TVS is trivially unitary, hence non-compact groups also have finite dimensional unitary representations, albeit only 1, the so-called trivial representation which takes any element of the group to the unit operator on the TVS in which you build the representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Irreducible* representations of compact groups must be finite-dimensional.  Compact groups can have infinite-dimensional representations, but those must necessarily be reducible.  Conversely, noncompact groups cannot have nontrivial irreducible unitary representations (I am not 100% positive about this.  Can somebody confirm that this is true?).  The unitarity here is key.  For example, $\mathbb{C}$ is a noncompact Lie group with a nonunitary one-dimensional irreducible representation (the "identity" representation).  Unitarity is a *natural* condition, however, because for a represetnation $V$ of a finite (or compact) group, you can choose an inner product on $V$ that makes the representation unitary.  In other words, all representations of finite (and compact) groups are essentially unitary.

This is probably not the best way to think about these groups (in terms of being parameterized by numbers, because in general, you'll need more than one chart to cover the manifold), but using your language, because $2\pi$ is identified with $0$ in $U(1)$, where as $v/c=1$ is *not* identified with $v/c=0$, you can't apply this same logic to both groups.

In any case, $U(1)=S^1$, and so is obviously compact.  The way you describe is probably the best intuitive way to see that the Lorentz group is not compact, and in fact this argument can be made into a proof.

Comment: Yes, for some reason I was blithely assuming the periodic identification wasn't important.

Comment: Is periodic identification the critical thing? or is it just that the interval must be closed. e.g. $v \in [0,c]$ would be compact, but $v \in [0,c)$ is non-compact?

Comment: In some sense periodic identification is absolutely crucial.  There are precisely two connected $1$-dimensional Lie groups:  $S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}$.  These two are distinguished precisely by 'periodic identification', and furthermore, $S^1$ is compact while $\mathbb{R}$ is not.  Even though $[0,c]$ or $[-c,c]$ might be compact, they are not Lie groups.

Comment: I also think it is mis-leading to *only* say that Lorentz boosts are parametrized by $v\in (-c,c)$.  They are, but you mustn't forget that the group law is not simply addition in $\mathbb{R}$; instead, it is given by the usual velocity addition formula in special relativity.  It turns out that this group law makes $(-c,c)$ into a Lie group which is isomorphic (as Lie groups) to $(\mathbb{R},+)$ via $\mathrm{arctanh}$.

Answer (score 6):

$U(1)$ is compact because rotation by 2$\pi$ and 0 are the same thing. So its not topologically an open interval, but a circle.

Comment: I think my confusion lies in whether the circle is a compact or closed space (in contrast to the interval [0,1)).

Comment: The circle is a compact space. Probably a little time spent on the wikipedia page would convince you of this. Be careful about calling a space closed - every space is closed in it's own topology but may be open or closed as a subset of larger space. Perhaps you should invest a little time in learning the basics of topology? It has a very large payoff to effort ratio.

Comment: I completely agree with BebopButUnsteady.  Every physicist should know enough point-set topology to understand at least basic manifold theory.

Comment: @James: Maybe it's just the word *compact* which is confusing. For spaces that are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, [compact = closed **and** bounded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem). This is good enough for most physics applications and gives a good intuition.

Comment: U(1) comes in two flavors, compact and noncompact. The noncompact one is the additive reals.

Comment: @Ron Maimon, only the compact one is usually called $U(1)$.

Comment: @Heidar: What's the noncompact one called?

Comment: @Ron Maimon, Heidar: Alright, alright enough with the semantics - I should have been more specific - it was clear from the question he meant the compact U(1).

Comment: Much of the confusion probably stems from the difference between terminology in terms of sets and manifolds. Also, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_manifold, where a compact manifold is described as one which is closed and possibly bounded, and that being "closed" implies having no boundary.

Comment: @RonMaimon There are only two connected one-dimensional manifolds:  $S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}$.  Both of them happen to be Lie Groups.  $S^1$ has many names:  $S^1$, $U(1)$, $\mathbb{R}P^1$, $\mathbb{T}^1$, $SO(2)$, $Spin(2)$, and the list probably goes on.  All of these have different definitions, which happen to coincide for these small cases.  To the best of my knowledge, there is really only the one name for $\mathbb{R}$.  Also, there aren't "two versions" of $U(1)$.  $U(1)=S^1$, period.  The "other version" you're thinking of is just $\mathbb{R}$.  It is not a "version" of $U(1)$.

Comment: It's called U(1) in a boatload of physics papers. For examples, look up Stueckelberg mechanism in "U(1)" gauge theory (necessarily noncompact)

Comment: @Ron Maimon: It's certainly good to be aware that people misuse terminology.  It's another thing entirely to propagate incorrect usages.

Comment: @wnoise: It is _not_ incorrect usage. It's very good usage that I use all the time. The "U(1)" Lie Algebra (which is trivial) describes both the additive reals and the multiplicative unit complex numbers. Why separate the additive reals? Are they not U(1)? When you compose them, do they not commute?

Comment: @Ron Maimon: Of course the groups U(1) and the reals under addition have the same Lie algebra.  So do SU(2) and SO(3), but calling one the other because it shares the same Lie algebra is still wrong.  I separate the additive reals from the circle group because their global behavior is different, and this matters in many cases.  Perhaps there should be some short term for "I don't care which of the groups that have the u(1) Lie algebra", but "U(1)" shouldn't be it.

Comment: @wnoise: There is a big difference, in that the limit of U(1) as the coupling constant goes to zero is the "R" version of U(1). The coupling constant can be made to be finite even for the R version, because charge can be artifically quantized. You can't do analogous things with Lie grops. Calling SO(3) SU(2) is not wrong, and people do that too--- the SO(3) gauge theory differs only in subtle ways from SU(2). You can say SU(2)/Z_2 to be more precise, but everyone knows what you mean when you say this stuff. It is wrong to insist on overly precise language at the expense of clear communication.

Comment: It's funny, but I find calling two things the same name to hinder clear communication.

Answer (score 2):

The topological manifold of the Lorentz group can be continuously embedded in the metric space $\mathbb{R}^{16}$ together with (metric) topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$ (direct product topology). The subset of Lorentzian boosts in 1 spatial direction can be parametrized by $\beta =v/c$ and is hence homeomorphic as a topological space with the open unit interval of $\mathbb{R}$ which is non-compact in the topology generated by the interval metric (by Heine-Borel theorem). Thus the Lorentz topological space is non-compact in the metric topology of $\mathbb{R}^{16}$, because there's no finite subcover for the space of Lorentzian boosts in 1 spatial direction.